# Create new row based on column value SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE 
   (EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50),
    EmployeeAddress NVARCHAR(50),
    WorkedLocations NVARCHAR(50), 
    IdNumbers NVARCHAR(50),
    UpdatedOn Date
)

Insert into @Employee
Values ('Alex',' Alex address','Cisco','12345',GETDATE()),
       ('John','John Address','Microsoft','23456',GETDATE()),
       ('Bob','Bob Address','CiscoMicrosoft','78903,89067',GETDATE()),
       ('Bill','Bill Address','Microsoft','54652',GETDATE())

 select * from @Employee
```

In 3rd row based on the 3rd column value a row has to be created and 4th row value should be split and assigned to respective 3rd column. Please see below required output

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE (
EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50)
, EmployeeAddress NVARCHAR(50)
, WorkedLocations NVARCHAR(50)
, IdNumbers NVARCHAR(50)
,UpdatedOn Date)

Insert into @Employee
Values ('Alex',' Alex address','Cisco','12345',GETDATE()),
       ('John','John Address','Microsoft','23456',GETDATE()),
       ('Bob','Bob Address','Cisco','78903',GETDATE()),
       ('Bob','Bob Address','Microsoft','89067',GETDATE()),
       ('Bill','Bill Address','Microsoft','54652',GETDATE())

 select * from @Employee
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You really shouldn't store delimited data like that. It violates 1NF and causes lots of pain. The only way you can deal with this is to parse your delimited values with a splitter of some sort. Here is an article with a number of options for this. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: What would be the delimiter to split? They both are simply sitting beside each other. I guess there should be something inbetween a space may be

Comment: Is there any rule where to split your data (e.g. CiscoMicrosoft -> Cisco + Microsoft)?

Comment: I would ask the Person who gives me such data, to split the data. Or to define rules so that you can split things up.

Comment: I have only these 3 static values in that column Cisco, Microsoft,CiscoMicrosoft, If I see CiscoMirosoft in that column I need split and assign 4th column value as Cisco, 78903 and m,icrosoft 89067 respectively

Comment: @Naresh, in fact this last statement was the most important and would have made things much easier...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will at least split your Multi-ID-column and deliver an output close to the needed. For splitting the company's names  you must give more information.

EDIT: As you statet, there is only Cisco, Microsoft and CiscoMicrosoft. So - in this special case, this should work:

```
    DECLARE @Employee TABLE 
   (EmployeeName NVARCHAR(50),
    EmployeeAddress NVARCHAR(50),
    WorkedLocations NVARCHAR(50), 
    IdNumbers NVARCHAR(50),
    UpdatedOn Date
)

Insert into @Employee
Values ('Alex',' Alex address','Cisco','12345',GETDATE()),
       ('John','John Address','Microsoft','23456',GETDATE()),
       ('Bob','Bob Address','CiscoMicrosoft','78903,89067',GETDATE()),
       ('Bill','Bill Address','Microsoft','54652',GETDATE());

SELECT *
      ,CASE WHEN IsMulti=0 THEN WorkedLocations ELSE CASE WHEN inx = 1 THEN 'Cisco' ELSE 'Microsoft' END END AS WorkedLocationResolved

FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmployeeAddress ORDER BY UpdatedOn) AS inx,*
    FROM
    (
        SELECT EmployeeName
              ,EmployeeAddress
              ,WorkedLocations
              ,x.y.value('.','int') AS IdNumber
              ,UpdatedOn
              ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',IdNumbers,1)>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsMulti 
        FROM @Employee AS empl
        CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN WorkedLocations='CiscoMicrosoft' THEN 'Cisco,Microsoft' ELSE WorkedLocations END) AS wl(wl)
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT CAST('<root><r>' + REPLACE(IdNumbers,',','</r><r>') + '</r></root>'  AS XML)
        ) AS IDs(v)
        CROSS APPLY IDs.v.nodes('/root/r') AS x(y)
    ) AS tbl
) AS tbl2
```

Comment: Say if I have delimiter as cisco, microsoft then how does it work? Can you please give sample code

Comment: I'll give you an answer soon

Comment: @Naresh, edited my answer. Plese up vote and or accept if helpful, thx

Comment: this is still showing 3 rd column values as ciscomicrosoft. I want ciscomicrosoft to be splited and cisco in one row and microsoft in one row

Comment: Look at the last column "WorkedLocationResolved". You can get them directly in your SELECT (instead of the "*").

Comment: @Naresh: This approach needs unique values in EmployeeAddress. This  is the PARTITION BY in ROW_NUMBER().

Comment: @Naresh, glad to hear this... If you don't mind please up vote this answer.. Everybody here lives on reputation points :-)